# Joomla 2.5 virtuemart user registration billing address

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, user-registration

I am using joomla 2.5 with virtuemart, I need to show Billing Address in user registration page. I need result like below image in joomal 2.5 user registration

[image].

If Any one know, Please give reply.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this path and add what you want
**/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/classes/ps_userfield.php**
in function **listuserfields**

And add what you want

Answer (score 1):

With Joomla 2.5, it’s very easy to add extra fields to the registration form. You have to turn on the user profile plugin, set the fields you want displayed, and publish a registration form.

1. From the Joomla Admin menu, click Extensions > Plugin Manager > User – Profile.
   Joomla displays the User Profile plugin screen.
2. From the Status list, select Enabled.
3. From the Basic Options list, for each field, select Required, Optional, or Disabled.
   Note: There are two lists: User profile fields for registration and administrator user forms and User profile fields for profile edit form. The first list is for the User Registration form. The second list is for the Profile Edit form. If you don’t want users to be able to see or edit these fields, you can disable them here.
4. Click Save & Close to save the User Profile settings.
   From the Joomla Admin menu, select Users > User Manager and then click Options.
5. Joomla displays the Users Configuration screen.